# Why can I not access an object property using a a different type which evaluates to the same string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

ResourceType is an object whose properties are values of NodeType.

ResourceType.engine === NodeType.engine === "engine".

Why can't I use a value of NodeType to access an object's value, which is keyed by a value of ResourceType when they both evaluate to the same string?

```
export declare enum NodeType {
    engine = "engine",
    agent = "agent",
    api = "api",
    pluginBuilder = "plugin-builder"
}

export class ResourceType {
  public static agent: NodeType.agent;
  public static engine: NodeType.engine;
}   

export class ResourceQuotaException extends HttpMetaException {
  constructor(resourceType: NodeType) {
    // Error message gets passed as first parameter
    super(ResourceQuotaException.MESSAGES[resourceType], HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
  public static readonly MESSAGES = {
    [ResourceType.agent]: 'Agent Limit Reached',
    [ResourceType.engine]: 'Engine Limit Reached'
  };
}
  
  throw new ResourceQuotaException(NodeType.engine); // Message is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake on my part.

Instead of

```
export class ResourceType {
  public static agent: NodeType.agent;
  public static engine: NodeType.engine;
}
```

it should be

```
export class ResourceType {
  public static agent = NodeType.agent;
  public static engine = NodeType.engine;
}
```